# Providing my own initializer for UICollectionViewFlowLayout

Tags: ios, swift

I'd like to provide my own initializer for my `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` subclass, for the purposes of calculating my `itemSize` property at runtime to scale my cells properly for different screen sizes. I understand that the simplest way to do so, is to adjust the default `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` from the `UICollectionViewController` like this:

```
//in UICollectionViewController
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let someWidth = ...
    let someHeight = ...
    let layout = collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: someWidth, height: someHeight)
}
```

However, I need to subclass `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` for the purposes of some custom layout for my `UICollectionReusableView`, so I thought it would be nice to declare the `itemSize` property in my layout subclass.

I am trying to make my own initializer, like so:

```
override init() {
    super.init()
    itemSize = CGSizeMake(someWidth, someHeight)
}
```

but I am greeted with the requirement:

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

When I attempt to load this viewController, I'm greeted with the `fatalError`. Next, I try to simply let the `super` implementation deal with it:

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

I recall various bits of information that is forcing my mind in a state of caution, something along the lines of: If one decides to subclassing something that requires the `NSCoding` things, one must do something to the variables that I added to the subclass.

Can anyone advise me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-- EDIT --

Is this what you're looking for?

```
class HmIsThisOK: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    var myCustomSize: CGSize = CGSizeMake(60.0, 23.5)
    override var itemSize: CGSize {
        get { return myCustomSize }
        set { myCustomSize = newValue }
    }
}
```

or does it just make sense to follow the usual protocol of initializing `itemSize` in your implementation of `prepareForLayout()`?

If none of that works for you, it's perfectly safe to do the required init junk and just add your code to the end of it after calling `super.init(...)`. You're not concerned with tying your custom init to the coding/encoding process, which has to do from awakening from the Nib file (usually Main.storyboard). Because the two inits() are required, you usually factor out your custom init code into a helper method.

Finally, If you are indeed awakening this object from the Nib file, you can use an overridden `awakeFromNib()` function to do custom initialization, without worrying about the init() prickliness.

Comment: I don't regard it as something wrong per say, but I'd like to bundle as much as the layout functionality in it's own subclass for enhanced reusability. `itemSize` belongs in `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and if I'm subclassing it, I might as well configure the whole layout in there instead.

Comment: What do you mean by declaring `itemSize` at class level?

Comment: Grammar a-hole: 'per se' ... anyway, absolutely, all my suggestions would go in the subclass. You would be doing an `override func viewDidLoad() { super.viewDidLoad(); /* your own stuff goes here */ }`

Comment: You're already declaring `itemSize` at class level; it just means within the enclosing braces of the class, not outside them (global scope) or inside a function (local function scope). So that it's a stored per-instance property. Just terminology, nothing new.

Comment: Oh yeah, should have recognized that. I can't override `viewDidLoad` in the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` subclass because it's not a `UIViewController` subclass. Attempting to declare `itemSize` at class level doesn't work either, since it's an inherited property from `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`. =[

Comment: Completely edited to account for this discussion. UIViewController discussion no longer appears in answer.